# Protocol parameters file to calculate min fee

Tags: cardano-cli, fee

I'm wondering, do I need to always generate a new protocols parameters JSON file when generating the min transaction fee?

I have a few transactions to make and I really don't like to be creating a new protocol parameters file before calculating the min fee. Is there a better approach for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating a new protocol parameters file just dumps the node's current parameters into a JSON format. Since the parameters are not constantly changing, **generating a new params file each time is not strictly necessary** - you can reuse it. However, if the parameters do change (as the did just now at the E319 boundary), then your fee calculation *might* be impacted if you use an outdated file.

Personally, I like to generate a new params file every epoch - this can be easily automated with `cron`.

Comment: Thank you for that, that sounds like a good approach. Every 5 days you regenerate the protocol parameters, right?

Comment: Yessir, only if I need to submit a transaction though.